# Time difference with daylight savings oracle

Tags: oracle

We are trying to perform arithmetic on a date. We are trying to add 1 day (24 hours) Here's a basic example...

```
select to_date('2018-10-06 22:00:00') + 1 from dual;
```

The result we get back from this is as follows...

```
2018-10-07 22:00:00
```

That seems good on paper, however we are in the Sydney timezone and during that interim period daylight savings occurs so the time should like something more like this...

```
2018-10-07 23:00:00
```

So I suppose my question is, when doing arithmetic in oracle is it possible to take into consideration daylight savings time. One idea was to convert the initial date to UTC and convert back to SYDNEY time, but it seems like a complicated solution that might already be handled by oracle functionality somewhere.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timestamp calculation with daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157708/timestamp-calculation-with-daylight-saving-time)

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do it directly with a date as those are not timezone aware.

You can start with a timestamp with time zone, e.g. as a timestamp literal:

```
select timestamp '2018-10-06 22:00:00 Australia/Sydney' + interval '1' day
from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2018-10-0622:00:00AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY'+
----------------------------------------------
2018-10-07 23:00:00.000000000 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
```

which you can cast back to a date if you want to discard that information:

```
select cast(timestamp '2018-10-06 22:00:00 Australia/Sydney' + interval '1' day as date)
from dual;

CAST(TIMESTAMP'2018
-------------------
2018-10-07 23:00:00
```

If you're starting from a date, e.g. in a table column, you can cast that to a timestamp and specify the time zone:

```
with your_table (your_date) as (
  select to_date('2018-10-06 22:00:00') from dual
)
select from_tz(cast(your_date as timestamp), 'Australia/Sydney') + interval '1' day
from your_table;

FROM_TZ(CAST(YOUR_DATEASTIMESTAMP),'AUSTRALIA/
----------------------------------------------
2018-10-07 23:00:00.000000000 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
```

and optionally cast back to date again to discard the fractional seconds and time zone information.

If your session time zone is Sydney then you could let that be set implicitly by casting to `timestamp with time zone` instead:

```
with your_table (your_date) as (
  select to_date('2018-10-06 22:00:00') from dual
)
select cast(your_date as timestamp with time zone) + interval '1' day
from your_table;
```

but it's generally better not to assume anything about the session environment that will run your code.

---

When the clocks go back at the end of DST you can specify which of the two possible values of times between 02:00 and 03:00 you mean by including a DST indicator:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM';

select timestamp '2018-04-01 01:00:00 Australia/Sydney AEDT' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2018-04-0101:00:
--------------------------
2018-04-01 01:00:00 +11:00

select timestamp '2018-04-01 02:00:00 Australia/Sydney AEDT' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2018-04-0102:00:
--------------------------
2018-04-01 02:00:00 +11:00

select timestamp '2018-04-02 02:00:00 Australia/Sydney AEST' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2018-04-0202:00:
--------------------------
2018-04-02 02:00:00 +10:00

select timestamp '2018-04-01 03:00:00 Australia/Sydney AEST' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2018-04-0103:00:
--------------------------
2018-04-01 03:00:00 +10:00
```

Although for me this only seems to work in 12.2.0.1; in earlier versions AEST/AEDT aren't recognised (though EST is). I'm not sure if that's just down the time zone file version - my 12.2 instance have version 26.

Going the other way if you have times that appear to be in the hour that doesn't exist when the clocks go forward at the start of DST, there isn't much you can do about it as they are invalid. If you populate fields using `sysdate` and the server is set to Sydney, or current_date and the session is, then that shouldn't  happen. Dates created with `to_date()` could be in that window, but then you probably need to figure out why and stop that happening.

Comment: One error, when you cast to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE then Oracle takes the SESSIONTIMEZONE not the server's time zone.

Comment: Cheers Alex, it seemed to work a treat. The one issue that catches is us is when we set the timestamp to 2pm on the day of Daylight Savings it throws an exception. I presume it's because that hour doesn't exist. As a 'dodgey' fix,  we throw an exception which simply returns the non affected day light savings time plus one hour... it seems to be good enough to cover us.

Comment: It seems to be logical that you get an exception if you enter a non existing time, what else would you expect? Regarding the ambiguous times (one hour exists twice due to day light savings) you can also specify this in timestamp literal. Please have a look at documentation, I don't have it in hand.